# Android. Best way to let the developer know of thrown exceptions

Tags: android, exception

What is the most common way to handle an exception, after it was thrown. I don't mean what to do to come back from the exception, not close the Activity or whatever. What i mean is how to let the developer know of the error number, the StackTrace and other log files that got created from the exception?

What is the most common way to send these to the developer? Or is it not common to do so?

Do you ask the user to send an email, which contains this information? Do you implement a form of some kind, similar to the ones used on websites on the contact page, and send the information automatically?

How do developers approach this issue? I'd really like to get some feedback from the users, so i know where, and if, my app crashes, but i'm not sure where exactly to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of tools which can catch exceptions and submit them to you (the developer). For example, look at [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) and [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net/crash-reports). Both of these are considerably more flexible than the built-in support which submits stacktraces to your Google Play developer account.

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't know how I'd feel about having 3rd parties handling how my app crashed, and you paying them for it.. :-|

Comment: "...your apps will be able to send all crash reports automatically to HockeyApp..." or even having them collect that kind of information..

Comment: Well, yes, that is rather the whole point. They offer a service so you don't have to set up your own online database hosting system to do it yourself. If you'd rather do it all yourself, then you are quite at liberty to do so. Although the way HockeyApp integrates with many common bug-tracking systems is awesome.

Comment: ACRA is free. HockeyApp is either free or paid depending on which package you want.

Comment: HockeyApp has a free trial, after the trial it is paid. There is an API to download all your data at any time. Your data won't be shared with anyone, see this blog post: http://www.hockeyapp.net/blog/2012/3/9/the-rules-of-hockeyapp.html Also all our SDKs are open source. Developers are the customers, not your users or data. In the end HockeyApp provides the server infrastructure to collect your data, group it and work with it so you don't have to do that. In addition it also has features helping you for beta testing. (Note: I am one of HockeyApps creators) Oh, and ACRA is also supported.

Comment: I am searching very hard to know if an application can read excpetions thrown by other applications. Backdrop of my question is this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565926/how-does-google-play-capture-exceptions-from-our-mobile/15566494?noredirect=1#comment22064635_15566494.

Answer (score 3):

Check [android.util.Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).

About how to manage the logs, it's up to you. You can send them to a server in the `Activity.onDestroy()` method, or specifically request them to the users reporting errors.

Comment: When an exception does get thrown, give a pop up containing the log and fetch the information about the user phone as well: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL then create a database on your own server to store those types of logs so you can check them out later and fix them when needed.

Comment: This comment is likely meant to be an answer. Use the *Add another answer* button at bottom ;)

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but how does one send information from the app to the server? Not even sure where to start searching to be honest :(

Comment: @m0skit0, what you said was the answer, I just wanted to give my two cents on top of what you said, no need to repeat it in my answer as well. We don't want to overflow the stackoverflow database with redundancies :0)

Comment: @AndreiBogdan you make an async call to a webservice that your server would provide. Search those keywords in google and you can find some good documentation. The webservice would dump the data into your database. The async call is during the time your program is still active, so that it will be independent of your running program operations.

Answer (score 3):

The Android OS has built-in functionality that helps you take care of this :)

When an Android app throws an unhandled exception, the OS automatically prepares the stack trace and asks the user if he or she would like to send it to the developer. If the user sends it, the developer can look the stack trace up in the developer console at http://market.android.com/publish.

Comment: but it also crashes the application (activity), which is not the case OP wants

Answer (score 3):

One of the simple way is to enclose all the exception prone codes within `try-catch` block and whenever exceptions are occurred, write them on a text file in your app's cache directory (preferably on sd-card). Later on, zip the text file and send it to your server in background. You may perform *sending* periodically.

By this way, you can avoid your application from being crash, yet still able to collect crash reports.