# How does google play capture exceptions from our mobile?

Tags: android, performance, google-play

I am wondering how would a Google play is capable of capturing list of errors occuring in the applications it has and showing it to the developer?

**Backdrop:**
We are trying to replicate an application like Google store?
We should maintain a list of enterprise application through our application. We wanted to implement an exception capturing framework through our application that is capable of capturing exception by our list of apps and show and store it in backend.

Answer (score 2):

I assume Android applications are tied to Google Play market so that when exceptions occurs, the crash report to be sent to them.

One possible solution would be to let your users implement some kind of library in order to publish apps on your market. That library should do nothing but catch exceptions and send crash reports to your servers (something like ACRA).

Though, as a developer, I don't think this approach is one good, unless you offer something very promising to developers (like app visibility, promotion, etc)

Comment: Thanks for your responde Andy Res, I will keep that as a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how Google Play does it, but for my needs I create my own `java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`:

```
class MyUncaughtExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private UncaughtExceptionHandler mDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler;

    MyUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        mDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread aThread, Throwable aThrowable) {
        // do your stuff
        mDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(aThread, aThrowable);
    }
}
```

And register it in `android.app.Application#onCreate`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler());
}
```

Comment: Delor, thanks for your reply. I think it won't suit my scenario. My requirement is to access exceptions generated by all other applications. To access some API in OS level and get the exceptions during runtime.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. the question was "How does google play capture exceptions from our mobile?"